Functions and their inverses using sets

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two sets and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function.
For a subset $A$ of $X$, define $f(A)$ to be the subset $\{f(a):a\in A \}$ of $Y$.
For a subset $B$ of $Y$, define $f^{-1}(B)$ to be the subset $\{x ∈ X : f(x)∈ B\}$ of $X$.

Prove that the following statements are False

$f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$ for all $A \subset X$

$f^{-1}(f(A)) = A$ for all $A \subset X$ iff $f(X) = Y$


I attempted this by representing $X$ and $Y$ as ovals and then drawing arrows corresponding to the functions given and reached the conclusion that the second statement is true (not sure about the first one), but the book says they are both false.

If you are new to these image set and preimage, try some examples to see what they are first. For example, $f(x)=x^2, f(x)=\ln x$ and $f(x)=e^{x}$. Now use $A$ as the domain, and try to see if the two statements on these three functions are true or not. Based on this, you can see some ideas/hints towards your proof.

For the first statement, think of a non-injective mapping f, e.g. there are two distinct elements in A map to the same element in B.
For the second statement, not sure what is after "if". I guess a non-injective & non-surjective map f may work.
